# How to verify the synchronization results of tsfle in Apache IoTDB when using `pipe`?

Tags: synchronized, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I synchronize tsfile from Apache IoTDB server A to server B through `pipe`, how to verify the synchronization results, and how to know whether the synchronization is successful? What result returned can be used to determine whether the tsfile received by server B is consistent with server A?

Answer (score 0):

After synchronizing your data to the receiving Apache IoTDB server B, as long as the data can be loaded to the database system, then this means the synchronization is successful. You can execute `show pipes` command, and if the result shows that the `pipe` is running, then this means there are no errors. In addition, you can also observe if there are any errors by checking the log records.